# Issue with page source after Adding html elements using jQuery append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery.I used jQuery `append()` to add `HTML` elements.After that viewing the page sorce that elements not displayed,but they already added and shown in webpage.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div id="button-div">
            <button id="test-btn">
                Click Me
            </button>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#test-btn').click(function (){
                $('#button-div').append("<div>This is sample text</div>");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actualy i want to a some elements to add html webpage and save that newly added elements to database.

then I used Jquery for collect the content,They it shown empty result.that the real issue.

Comment: If you are checking the source file then dynamically added element wont be there. They are added DOM but not the source file.

Comment: You mean they are in visible in souce code but not in webpage?

Comment: yes,Actually I want to collect that added elements and add to it mysql database.but collecting that newly added elements via jQuery they shown null result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the DOM inspector. Viewing page source will only load static HTML, since your javascript execution added the dynamic HTML, it won't be visible that way.

Comment: Actually I want to collect that added elements and add to it mysql database.But collecting that newly added elements via jQuery using ` $(this).find("#id")` they shown null result.How can I do it @chovy ?

Comment: `$("#id")` is good enough. I'd have to see an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/V237B/
I want to add element to list call "Todo" and Save that all 3 list items into mysql database.when calling Save ToDo it's only get the hardcoded list items.

Answer (score 2):

Your elements will not appear in the sourcecode. You can see what happened if you use the element inspector. In Chrome on windows you can show using F12 key or cmd+alt+i on mac osx.

Answer (score 1):

Page source only shows the html that is added on page load, html added after page load via javascript or jquery can be viewed using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) Inspect or chrome inspector.

Comment: Interesting fact. So then how to get the IDs of the newly generated elements?

Comment: you would have to find them via a common class applied on them via js or jquery